# vector iterator incrementable when erasing element of vector in 2 for loops

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, erase

I am currently programming a little game for the console with an 2D map. 2 Elements of my game are: destroying fields and an enemy, which spreads in a random direction (its getting bigger). These two "entities" are saved in a structure which contains two vectors (X and Y). I am now trying to erase an element of "_Enemy"(<-private instance of the structure in a class, same as "_DestroyedFields") if you destroy the field where the enemy is.

I tried a lot of different variations to do so and whats giving me the error least is this method (I already searched the internet for a while now an couldn't find a answer to my question):

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator itEX = _Enemys.X.begin(), itEY = _Enemys.Y.begin();
     itEX != _Enemys.X.end() && itEY != _Enemys.Y.end();
     ++itEX, ++itEY) {
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator itX = _DestroyedFields.X.begin(), 
                                      itY = _DestroyedFields.Y.begin(); 
           itX != _DestroyedFields.X.end() && itY != _DestroyedFields.Y.end(); 
           ++itX, ++itY) {
    if (*itY == *itEY && *itX == *itEX){
        itEY = _Enemys.Y.erase(itEY);
        itEX = _Enemys.X.erase(itEX);
    }
  }
}
```

PS: sorry if my english isn't the best, im german ^^

PSS: if you wanna watch over my whole code, you can find it on Github: https://github.com/Aemmel/ConsoleGame1

Comment: Currently, you increase your iterator when you do the `erase`...

Comment: I suggest to use a simple struct for position.

Comment: @Jarod42 whar do you mean with simple struct?

Comment: Which double for loop implementation is being used?  The version on git assumes that X and Y are always the same size.  The one above should be a better way to search for the correct elements.

Comment: @CPlusPlusOOAandD Whoops, didn't notice it wasn't the same ^^. The example above is used.

Comment: using `struct Position {int x; int y};`, then you have `std::vector<Position> _Enemys.Pos`...

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah. I'll try that. (But whats really the difference, would it cause less bugs or would it be safer in generell or would it just be easiert to use?)

Comment: easier to read/write/use, so less bug.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ok, thank you for your advice. I'll try that and hopefully it will also prevent the bug.

Comment: @Jarod42 The bug still happens. At the exact same point...

Comment: Please don't add the word "solved" to the title. The way to indicate that your problem is solved is to accept an answer (by selecting the green check mark). If no existing answer captures the solution, feel free to post an answer yourself.

Answer (score 2):

After erasing using iterator `it`, you cannot use `it` further as `it` is invalidated. You should use a result of a call to erase which is new, valid iterator.

```
for( it = v.begin(); it != v.end();)
{
   //...   
   if(...)
   {
      it = v.erase( it); 
   }
   else
   {
      ++it;
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, it gives out the error: "vector iterator not dereferencable"

Comment: using your method instead of mine with _Enemys(so itEX and itEY). And I think it always crashes in the if statement (I'm printing out when it erases and in the else statement and it stops printing after the if-statement, when the condition is true)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the bug with first: making a "simple structure"(struct Entity{int X; intY} and then std::vector [insert name here]) and then with adding an break; if the condition is true.

```
for (Uint itE = 0; itE < _Enemys.size(); ++itE){
        for (Uint it = 0; it<_DestroyedFields.size(); ++it){
            if (_Enemys.at(itE).Y == _DestroyedFields.at(it).Y 
                && _Enemys.at(itE).X == _DestroyedFields.at(it).X){
                _Enemys.erase(_Enemys.begin()+itE);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you add `bool operator == (const Position& lhs, const Position& rhs)
{
    return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y;
}`, then you may write the condition : `_Enemys.at(itE) == _DestroyedFields.at(it)` (or with `[]` : `_Enemys[itE] == _DestroyedFields[it]`)

Comment: BTW, you still increase `itE` when you erase, so you may miss the removal of successive elements.

Answer (score 0):

With `struct Position {int x; int y;};` and some utility operators,
you may do one of the following: (https://ideone.com/0aiih0)

```
void filter(std::vector<Position>& positions, const std::vector<Position>& destroyedFields)
{
    for (std::vector<Position>::iterator it = positions.begin(); it != positions.end(); ) {
        if (std::find(destroyedFields.begin(), destroyedFields.end(), *it) != destroyedFields.end()) {
            it = positions.erase(it);
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if input are sorted, you may use a 'difference':

```
std::vector<Position> filter2(const std::vector<Position>& positions, const std::vector<Position>& destroyedFields)
{
    std::vector<Position> res;
    std::set_difference(positions.begin(), positions.end(),
                        destroyedFields.begin(), destroyedFields.end(),
                        std::back_inserter(res));
    return res;
}
```